# Сначала полная загрузка html кода, потом показать

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте. Сейчас попробую объяснить свою ситуацию: в общем есть на сайте блоки, высота и ширина которых зависит от других блоков. Поэтому в `jQuery` писал типа:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#block2').height($('#block1').hight()-10);
});
```

И по этому когда страница загружается, блоки прыгают и потом становятся на свои места. Ничего в голову не приходит. Что можете посоветовать? Или как вы решали вопрос в таких ситуациях?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, порой это бывает проблема не простая. Столкнулся однажды с чем-то подобным.

Я ставил на BODY visibility: hidden, а когда все условия выполнялись и страница была готова к показу - делал visibility: visible.

Но я не рекомендую использовать правило display: none на все тело страницы, оно может привести к непонятно откуда взявшимся "поломкам" на странице.

Comment: Дада display: none не помогло, я уже попробовал. а вот  visibility: hidden даже в голову не пришло, щас попробую

Comment: ПОлучилось, спаисбо))

Answer (score 4):

`$(window).load()` ждет, когда загрузятся все изображения на странице. Естественно это происходит не сразу. Сначала загружается `DOM`. Потом отдельным запросом загружаются картинки. Если картинок много или они большие, то высота блока так и не поменяется до загрузки всех этих изображений.
 Как дополнение к варианту, предложенному [[@zhenyab](/users/6147/zhenyab)](/users/6147/zhenyab) предлагаю сделать следующие действия, если уже не сделали:

1. Перенести все скрипты вниз
       страницы перед закрывающим тегом
       `</body>`. Это предотвратит блокировку
       страницы до загрузки всех скриптов и
       избавит от необходимости
       подписываться на событие загрузки
       документа `$(document).ready()` или на
       событие полной загрузки страницы
       `$(window).load()`.
2. Перенести все функции меняющие структуру `DOM` при
       начальной загрузке страницы в начало
       файла.
3. Переписать функцию
       изменения высоты элемента на чистый
       `js`. Она будет исполняться быстрее,
       так как не будет использовать
       `jQuery`.

Comment: Спасибо, за отличный, полезный совет! Буду делать как вы сказали!